# Apply mark_boundaries for contours on segmented images

Tags: python-3.x, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I can't get the skimage function to work to create a contour mask with mark_boundaries on Python

```
import skimage.segmentation as seg
import skimage.color as color
from skimage import restoration
from skimage import img_as_float
%matplotlib inline

image=io.imread('C:\\...\\...\\input.png')
im_float  =  img_as_float ( image )
im_denoised = restoration.denoise_nl_means(im_float, h=0.05)
plt . imshow ( im_denoised ,  cmap = 'gray' )
def image_show(image, nrows=1, ncols=1, cmap='gray'):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(25, 14))
    ax.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
    ax.axis('off')
    return fig, ax
image_show(color.label2rgb(image_slic,im_denoised,kind='avg'))
image_felzenszwalb=seg.felzenszwalb(im_denoised)
image_felzenszwalb_colored=color.label2rgb(image_felzenszwalb,im_denoised,
                                           kind='avg')
image_show(image_felzenszwalb_colored)

#mark_boundaries

mask=seg.mark_boundaries(image_felzenszwalb_colored,label_img 
                         ('segmentation_mask'), 
                         color=1,1,1),background_label=None)
```

I received:

> ~\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\skimage\segmentation\boundaries.py in find_boundaries(label_img, connectivity, mode, background) 156 [False, True, True, False, False]], dtype=bool) 157 """ --> 158 if label_img.dtype == 'bool': 159 label_img = label_img.astype(np.uint8) 160 ndim = label_img.ndim AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype

What's wrong?

Comment: Please post the full traceback including line number.

Comment: ~\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\skimage\segmentation\boundaries.py in find_boundaries(label_img, connectivity, mode, background)
    156            [False,  True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
    157     """
--> 158     if label_img.dtype == 'bool':
    159         label_img = label_img.astype(np.uint8)
    160     ndim = label_img.ndim

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Comment: In your last call, you use `label_img` as an argument but I don't see it defined anywhere in your code. Where is `label_img` defined? Also, there is a comma missing between `label_img` and `('segmentation_mask')`.

Comment: I forgot to write it down. Sorry. I have changed but the error remains the same.
How should it be defined label_img?
label_img = 'Segmentation_mask' ?

Comment: Can you try changing the last call to be: `mask=seg.mark_boundaries(im_float, image_felzenswalb, color=(1,1,1), background_label=None)` ? Have you read https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.mark_boundaries?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm new to programming language. Yes, I've read it, but now I'm getting another error: ~\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py in __init__(self, int_type)
    504         self.key = "%s%d" % (self.kind, self.bits)
    505         if self.kind not in 'iu':
--> 506             raise ValueError("Invalid integer data type %r." % (self.kind,))
    507 
    508     def min(self):

ValueError: Invalid integer data type 'f'.